# Slide a new UIViewcontroller from top

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

John Lluch has [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController), this controller container library that allows one to add slide navigation on letf and right side of a central controller. Is there a library available that also allows one to push a controller from top or bottom - or has someone cooked up a version that does that ?

Answer (score 0):

I just created [NDOverlayViewController](https://github.com/neildavis/NDOverlayViewController) to do something like this. Actually it can overlay/slide one view controller over another from any edge with variable offset, extent and animation options. I created it as an experiment but maybe it will be helpful to somebody?